# How can I restrict who can make changes using interfaces?

Tags: c#

I have a IHasTag interface, a TaggableItem class that implements IHasTag and a TaggingManager class which I want to make it the only one responsible for setting or clearing the Tags but I've been struggling all day trying to implement but with no luck.
How can I make this possible?

```
public class TaggableItem : TaggingManager.IHasTag
{
    public string Tag { get; }  // read only
}

public class TaggingManager
{
    public interface IHasTag
    {
        string Tag { get; }
    }

    private List<IHasTag> _taggedItems = new();

    public void TagItem(IHasTag item, string tag)
    {
        item.Tag = tag;  // not working
        _taggedItems.Add(item);
    }

    public void ClearAllTags()
    {
        foreach (var item in _taggedItems)
        {
            item.Tag = "":  // not working
        }
        _taggedItems.Clear();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I followed Thomas' suggestion and this is what I end up doing. I know it's not perfect, though. Thank you all for your advices.

```
public interface ITaggable
{
    string? Tag { get; }
}

public interface ISelectable
{
    bool IsSelected { get; }
}

public interface IItem : ITaggable, ISelectable
{
}

public class Item : IItem
{
    protected Item() { }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    // 'Item' will be created here returning IItem.
    // So, unless you 'cast' it, you can't set 'Tag' or 'IsSelected'.
    public static IItem CreateItem() => new Item();
}

public class SelectionManager
{
    protected List<object> _items = new();
    public void Select(ISelectable item)
    {
        if (item is Item selectable)
        {
            selectable.IsSelected = true;
            _items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    public void Unselect(ISelectable item)
    {
        if (item is Item selectable)
        {
            selectable.IsSelected = false;
            _items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}

public class TaggingManager
{
    private List<object> _items = new();
    public void Tag(ITaggable item, string tag)
    {
        if (item is Item taggable)
        {
            taggable.Tag = tag;
            _items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    public void Untag(ITaggable item)
    {
        if (item is Item taggable)
        {
            taggable.Tag = string.Empty;
            _items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With two interfaces: IReadTag and IWriteTag. The TaggingManager gets a reference to IWriteTag (or both) and everyone else just gets a IReadTag.

Comment: Can you place the `TaggingManager` and `TaggableItem` (and other classes with `IHasTag` implementation, if any) it the separate assembly?

Comment: You could cast it back to `TaggableItem`, check it's not null and then apply the `Tag`. It's not a great solution but it achieves what you are trying to do.

Comment: This question may lead to a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @ThomasWeller Can you elaborate with an answer with code please? I tried using explicit interfaces but got into a labyrinth of accessibility difference.

Comment: @Serg Yes. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @IanMercer I think casting to TaggableItem won't let me edit the Tag property.

Comment: @MickyD I'm not familiar with 'CAS' or 'Partial Trust' so I googled it but I don't see how it helps me with this. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Andrew Could you elaborate in the question what is problem you are dealing with here?  It's unclear why your interface needs to look like this. Ask yourself: why are you trying to solve your problem like this?

Comment: @Xerillio I need to deal with a huge collection (>10K) and I need performance as possible. I think making changes(ex: TagAll, ClearAll) in a single place (TagManager) is the way to go. I also want to apply this to other stuff like ISelectable, etc.

Comment: You need elaborate about `restrict` and `using interfaces`, these are the core elements in the title.

Comment: 10000 is not much. Don't worry about performance before you have actual performance data from a profiler.

Comment: @shingo By "restrict", I mean that I want the TaggingManager to be the only one who can change the Tag property. And by "using interfaces", it would be something like ThomasWeller suggested. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'm worried too much before implementing, I guess?

Comment: @Andrew you'd need to make it `public get, internal set` too so that it's only accessible inside the assembly you are creating and not by external callers if you wanted to try the casting approach.

Comment: @IanMercer I tried around adding the accessors you said but I didn't get it work. Where exactly should I add `public get, internal set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to have two interfaces for two purposes: reading and writing.

```
public interface IHasTag        // interface for reading. Maybe IReadTag
{
    string Tag { get; }
}

public interface ITagChange     // interface for writing. Maybe IWriteTag
{
    string Tag { set; }
}

public class TaggableItem : IHasTag, ITagChange   // implement both
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}

// Tagging manager gets write access (ITagChange)
public class TaggingManager
{
    private List<ITagChange> _taggedItems = new ();

    public void TagItem(ITagChange item, string tag)
    {
        item.Tag = tag;
        _taggedItems.Add(item);
    }

    public void ClearAllTags()
    {
        foreach (var item in _taggedItems)
        {
            item.Tag = "";
        }
        _taggedItems.Clear();
    }
}

// Everyone else has read access only (IHasTag)
class SomeoneElse
{
    private List<IHasTag> _taggedItems = new ();
    public void DoSomething(IHasTag item)
    {
        _taggedItems.Add(item);
        var tag = item.Tag; // do something with the tag
    }
}

class Instantiation
{
    public void Main()
    {
         TaggableItem x = new TaggableItem();
         TaggingManager m = new TaggingManager();
         m.TagItem(x, "name");
         SomeoneElse s = new SomeoneElse();
         s.DoSomething(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: But someone can always cast the object to ITagChange and change the value.

Comment: @shingo: he can't, unless he relies on internals of the implementation, which he shouldn't. The interface is the contract and if someone casts and the cast fails, it's his fault. You could always put a wrapper class around it to make the cast fail.

Comment: @ThomasWeller But in Main(), you can set the Tag directly `x.Tag = "NewTag";` and this is what I want to prevent.

Comment: @Andrew: you need to trust at least some code, ideally your own.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is to move the "getter" also to the `TagManager`. Then the manager is responsible for the tags. The object itself does not even need to know about the tags.

You still can restrict this by exchanging `object` with an `interface`.

```
public class TagManager
{
    private Dictionary<object, string> _tagedItems = new Dictionary<object, string>();

    public bool HasTag(object item)
    {
       return _tagedItems.ContainsKey(item);
    }

    public string GetTag(object item)
    {
      return  _tagedItems[item];
    }

    public void SetTag(object item, string tag)
    {
        if(!HasTag(item))
        {
            _tagedItems.Add(item, tag);
        }
        else
        {
            _tagedItems[item] = tag;
        }        
    }
}
```

I don't think that this is really a answer to the OP, but one possible solution for the underlying problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry, I didn't mean to ask a problematic question. With your suggestions I'll be able to make TagManager responsible for all tagging, but using a Dictionary in HasTag() or GetTag()  I'm think I'll be having performance issues since I need to deal with a huge amount (> 10K) of items.